# How to use LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder to log JSON only?

Tags: json, spring, logback

for my Spring Boot service I use the following logback.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <!-- without this line nothing will be printed to the console -->
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.apache" level="INFO"/> <!-- SECURITY -->
    <logger name="httpclient" level="INFO"/>


    <appender name="jsonConsoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <providers>
                <timestamp/>
                <version/>
                <message/>
                <loggerName/>
                <threadName/>
                <logLevel/>
                <mdc/>
                <!-- repeats log arguments as root json fields -->
                <arguments/>
                <pattern>
                    <pattern>
                        {
                        "myField": {
                        "mySubField": "%mdc{abc}"
                        },
                        "myField2": "%mdc{abc}"
                        }
                    </pattern>
                    <omitEmptyFields>true</omitEmptyFields>
                </pattern>
                <logstashMarkers/>
            </providers>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="jsonConsoleAppender" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

However, this will print the logging message using logger.info("xxxx") as well as the JSON in the next line. I only want the JSON to be printed not the regular line. How can I achieve this?

I found this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/java-log-json-output

It features this code:

```
Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("CONSOLE_JSON_APPENDER");
logger.debug("Debug message");
```

Is this a recommended way which wil only print JSON? Where is the information about the current class which you normally pass when creating a logger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently removing this line did the trick:

```
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
```